# emcee MCMC sampling not converging to appropriate parameter values

Tags: python, sampling, mcmc, emcee

I'm trying to implement `emcee` MCMC sampling in Python with a predefined likelihood function to find the best boundary between two populations of data.

For `emcee` see: http://dfm.io/emcee/current/user/line/

The likelihood function calculates the true positive and true negative classifications, given some linear boundary line, and is used to minimise the difference between the two values whilst maximising their sum.

This way you can imagine a TP and TN rate of 1 respectively will give a likelihood value of 1 while TP and TN rates of 0 will return a likelihood value of 0.

But when I attempt to sample the parameter space for `m` and `b`, the gradient and offset (or bias), for the boundary line, I get some wildly big and/or small values for the walks.

I have put an example code below which generates some nicely divided populations and then MCMCs around the initial guesses of the parameter values. I'm unsure as to why the MCMC chains don't converge nicely to an appropriate value here so any help would be greatly appreciated.

The following code should run out-of-the-box.

```
import emcee
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#generate some test x and y data
folded_xy_train = np.random.uniform(0,1,10000) #test x data
folded_z_train = np.random.uniform(0,1,10000) #test y data
#define the true gradient and offset for the boundary line
m_true, b_true = 5,-2.5

#generate labels for the test data
rounded_labels_train = np.ones(len(folded_z_train))
model = (m_true*folded_xy_train) + b_true
difference = model - folded_z_train
rounded_labels_train[difference<0] = 0

#show the test data
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(folded_xy_train,folded_z_train,c=rounded_labels_train,s=1.0)

#define a likelihood function for the boundary line       
def lnlike(theta, x, y, labels):
        m, b = theta
        model = (m*x) + b
        difference = model - y
        classifications = np.ones(len(y))
        classifications[difference<0]=0
        cfm = confusion_matrix(labels,classifications)
        cm = cfm.astype('float') / cfm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        tn, fp, fn, tp = cm.ravel()
        likelihood_val = (0.5*(tp+tn))/(1+np.abs(tp-tn))
        ln_like = -np.log(likelihood_val)
        return ln_like

#define a wide flat prior         
def lnprior(theta):
    m, b, = theta
    if 0 < m < 10 and -20 < b < 5:
        return 0.0
    return -np.inf 

#define the posterior         
def lnprob(p, x, y, labels):
    lp = lnprior(p)
    if not np.isfinite(lp):
        return 0
    return lp + lnlike(p, x, y, labels)

#setup the MCMC sampling  
nwalkers = 4
ndim = 2
p0 = np.array([4.2,-2]) + [np.random.rand(ndim) for i in range(nwalkers)]
sampler = emcee.EnsembleSampler(nwalkers, ndim, lnprob, args=(folded_xy_train, folded_z_train, rounded_labels_train))
sampler.run_mcmc(p0, 500)

#extract the MCMC paramater value chains       
samples = sampler.chain[:, 50:, :].reshape((-1, ndim))        

#view the parameter chains        
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(samples[:,0])
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(samples[:,1])
```

The initial test data, showing an obvious boundary line for given x y data (coloured by binary class label):

[image]

The sample walks, showing strange sampling for the gradient parameter (top) and offset parameter (bottom). The x-axis denotes the MCMC walk step number and the y-axis denotes the MCMC parameter values at a given step:

[image]

Comment: What do these plots show (you should label the axes)? What would you expect them to look like instead?

Comment: I've updated the post to help explain your question. I expect them to look like MCMC walks which tend to hover around the true m and b parameter values but have take stochastic walks around them.

Comment: There seem to be 2 modes on your sample distributions. Zero values (but with a crazy scale 1e123) and huge values. Can you exclude the huge values and zoom in to see if the "zero values" are distributed correctly? And maybe look at the corner plot (see e.g. [here](http://dfm.io/emcee/current/user/line/))  too.

Comment: Hmm, I find that if you plot the log of the samples instead in the plotting routine then you find that the samples aren't bimodal but instead just cover the entire space between 0 and the big number evenly. To me that means the acceptance ratio for a step in the MCMC is too low and so it's just accepting any step it proposes but I can't see any way in the docs to change that. http://dfm.io/emcee/current/api/#emcee.EnsembleSampler.sample